# Replace Value Text Over Multiple Lines

Tags: c#

I have multiple text files and I need to replace a string inside with something else.  The text files can have up to 500 of this reoccurrences .

The example below I need to replace everything after Synopsis  with whatever string I choose such as not available.

I can read the file and I even tried to make 2 markers start and end but not working:

List of all books

Romance

```
Book number: 1
Title : Something Title
Author : Some Author
ISBN: 45425425423
Written Date : Some date
Release Date: Some date
Characters: Blah Blah
Genre: Romance
Synopsis : Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah


Book number: 2
Title : Something Title
Author : Some Author
ISBN: 45425425423
Written Date : Some date
Release Date: Some date
Characters: Blah Blah
Genre: Romance
Synopsis : Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah

Book number: 3
Title : Something Title
Author : Some Author
ISBN: 45425425423
Written Date : Some date
Release Date: Some date
Characters: Blah Blah
Genre: Romance
Synopsis : Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
       Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
```

Comedy

```
Book number: 1
Title : Something Title
Author : Some Author
ISBN: 45425425423
Written Date : Some date
Release Date: Some date
Characters: Blah Blah
Genre: Romance
Synopsis : Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
```

This is the code i tried so far.

```cs
string[] filelines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt", Enconding.UTF8)

string markS = "Synopsis :"

string MarkE = "Book number:"

for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
{
    string line = fileLines[i];
   
    int start = line.IndexOf(markS);

    int end = line.LastIndexOf(markE);
    Console.WriteLine(start + " " + end);
    // if (start >= 0 && end >= 0)
    if (start >= 0 && end >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        int length = line.IndexOf(markE) + markE.Length - start;
        //include the markers in the substring
        //in case the substring occurs elsewhere without the markers
        var textToReplace = line.Substring(start, length);

        //add the markers to the relacement
        string replacement = markS + replacedText + markE;
        var result = line.Replace(textToReplace, replacement);
        fileLines[i] = result;

    }
    File.WriteAllLines(@"test2.txt", fileLines);`your text`
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly. In particular example input should be inline in the question as text (ideally as compile time constant in the code), expected/actual output written out explicitly and errors (if any) shown as text.

Comment: "synonpsis" and "book number" do not appear on the same line ever, how do you expect this to work?

Comment: you need to loop till you find "Book number" then loop till you get "Synopsis"

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions and `Regex.Replace` we can replace the text as so:

```
var pattern = @"(^Synopsis\s:)(.+?)(^Book\snumber|\Z)";

var replacements = 
      Regex.Replace(text, 
                    pattern, 
                    $"$1 Jabberwocky {Environment.NewLine}$3", 
                    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

The above code will replace the multline "Synopsis" value with "Jabberwocky".

You may need to tweak the `(^Book\snumber|\Z)` capture with the section headers like `(^Book\snumber|Romance|Comedy|\Z)`. But I leave that up to you to work out since it's your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your post states that you **need to replace a string inside with something else** and you *could* consider the entire file as "one long string" and do some processing on that. The `Regex` solution is probably a great way to go in that case.

But I read your code carefully from the perspective of what you're actually trying to *do*. Ok, so my crystal ball isn't 100% but I believe that if we meet back up a few weeks from now, it will have occurred to you want certain elements:

- A `class` that represents a Book.
- A *serialization method* (like Json) that can take a file and turn it into a Book and vice versa.
- A way to search the books (like SQLite) based on the properties in the Book class.

Having a `Book` class would simplify the substitution that you want to do because the `Synopsis` property would already be separated out. Then you could perform a standard `string.Replace` in a targeted way.

---

**Book class**

```
class Book
{
    public string? BookNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Author { get; set; }
    public string? ISBN { get; set; }
    public string? Written { get; set; }
    public string? Release { get; set; }
    public string? Characters { get; set; }
    public string? Genre { get; set; }
    public string? Synopsis { get; set; }
    // Display
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            $"Book number : {BookNumber}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Title : {Title}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Author : {Author}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"ISBN : {ISBN}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Written Date : {Written}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Release Date : {Release}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Characters : {Characters}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Genre : {Genre}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Synopsis : {Synopsis}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

Replace:

```
book.Synopsis = book.Synopsis.Replace("Blah", "Marklar");
```

[image: test]

---

**Serialization** - The hard way

You stated that the `.txt` files are on disk. Here's a method that uses the string representations in your post to turn a "file" into a `Book`.

```
public Book(string file)
{
    var synopsis = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
    {
        var parse = line.Split(':').Select(_ => _.Trim()).ToArray();
        if (parse.Length == 1)
        {
            synopsis.Append("\t" + parse[0] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            var property = parse[0];
            switch (property)
            {
                case "Book number": BookNumber = parse[1]; break;
                case "Title": Title = parse[1]; break;
                case "Author": Author = parse[1]; break;
                case "ISBN": ISBN = parse[1]; break;
                case "Written Date": Written = parse[1]; break;
                case "Release Date": Release = parse[1]; break;
                case "Characters": Characters = parse[1]; break;
                case "Genre": Genre = parse[1]; break;
                case "Synopsis": synopsis.Append(parse[1] + Environment.NewLine); break;
                default: Debug.Assert(false, $"Error reading '{property}'"); break;
            }
        }
    }
    Synopsis = synopsis.ToString();
}
```

That's a lot of work, but now you can **replace value over multiple lines** starting with a raw file:

```
book = new Book("492C9F2A7E73.txt");
book.Synopsis = book.Synopsis.Replace("Blah", "Marklar");
```

---

**Serialization** - An easier way

But also please consider `using` something like the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet to simplify your serialization. It still writes the file in plain text and you'll even see the ':' character used in a similar way to your file listings. But the format lets Json reconstruct a `Book` object directly.

*SAVE*

```
var path = Path.Combine(dir, $"{book.ISBN}.json");
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book));
```

Result in file (this is after doing the replacement):

```
{
  "BookNumber": "2",
  "Title": "Something Title",
  "Author": "Some Author",
  "ISBN": "7E092CB94CCD",
  "Written": "Some date",
  "Release": "Some date",
  "Characters": "Blah Blah",
  "Genre": "Romance",
  "Synopsis": "Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar\r\n\tMarklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar\r\n\tMarklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar\r\n\tMarklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar Marklar\r\n"
}
```

*LOAD*

```
var book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(File.ReadAllText("492C9F2A7E73.json"));
```

*QUERY*

```
var romanceBooks = database.Query<Book>("SELECT * FROM books WHERE Genre='Romance'");
```

There's more than one way to do what you asked. The benefit of doing something like this is to set you up going forward for a search engine using the Book class.

Comment: I liked you class idea. it would make much easier.  One question,  what if not all the books contain the JSON data.  Let say one of doesn't have author, another isbn.

Comment: Great question, and I'm happy to say that Json is _very_ tolerant of those things. On a Save, if the property isn't there at all it simply doesn't write a line in the file. On a Load, properties that aren't in the file will stay at their default values. It's one of the most robust libraries I've ever used.

Comment: Perhaps the book line up wasn't a perfect example.  The actual txt files are error messages I get from car and depending on error that is how many lines between the Error # and the Error Message.
so an error could be
Error #1   Power Type#2

Comment: I'm wondering if you'd like to experiment with the minimal code I used to test my answer? Would that be helpful? It's in my GitHub repo and you can just [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/books-text-replacement.git) it if you like. As far as `car` goes is that in your post? I don't recall it. OH is this like an auto diagnostic you mean?

Comment: could be 
Error #1 Power Type#2
engine on = false   color = R  Level =2
Name =
System affected
Time
Error Data:
Message: 

Cycle 10
Error #1 Power Type#3
engine on = true   color = G  Level =5
max pwr = 
Stop Time
Pressure =
Name =
System affected
Time
Error Data:
Message:

Comment: So with your JSON,  I could only create the synopsis and leave the rest blank

Comment: Do _you_ get to say how the messages are formatted? Or do you have to work with what's given to you by some diagnostic or something like that?

Comment: Got work with what i got

Comment: I see. Ok I guess to summarize you may have to do the serialization the long way but for sure I think it's easier if you make a class whether it turns out that you can use the Json or not. Good luck! And if this has been helpful please consider rating my answer.  Thx!